# OutOfMemoryError during build

Tags: android, gradle, memory, openvpn

I am using Android sdk 31

When I am trying to build https://github.com/schwabe/ics-openvpn > main.

I am constantly get the following error:

```
Execution failed for task ':main:packageSkeletonOvpn2DebugAndroidTest'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact$IncrementalSplitterRunnable
   > java.lang.OutOfMemoryError (no error message)
...
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

After some searching on the internet it seems to adjust the memory size in [gradle.properties](https://gradle.properties/).
I updated the line to:
`org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx8608m`

I also adjust the memory file > settings > memory settings  > adjusted to 4GB
For the record I have more then 60GB of RAM so there should be no problem.But still the errors keeps coming.
It doesnt matter how big the memory size is.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you sure the heap memory settings are applied to Gradle processes, there are global system env variables which can override all your settings? Also make sure to kill all active Gradle daemons to make sure the new settings are applied. Last I would check process manager of the OS or tools like VisualVM what the real heal settings of the Gradle process(es) are.

Comment: Are you running multiple android studio instances on your computer ? I had similar issues when I was running 3-4 instances and then building in one of them. Once I closed others,  I was able to build.

Comment: I checked and there is only 1 instance running.
@Robert I have checked the settings in my gradle file and in my Android studio build settings both have the right memory size, are there any other locations where the memory settings can be adjusted/aplied?

Comment: Before starting to find potential fixed configuration, better use VisualVM and see if your heap configuration was applied on the gradle worker. It it was applied and you still get OOM, then something is wrong with the build script or a used plugin.